# How to hide a div after pressing another div?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've finally managed to make a `div` popup after a certain time in JS but the problem is, I can't get the `div` to disappear, I want to make it so the `div` disappear after being clicked but, how?

Sorry for asking but I've been looking for ages for something as simple as it sounds but I can't seem to figure out how to make a div clickable and then make it disappear when clicked thus I suppose don't have any important code to show.

**Edit**: It seems like showing some code is still important but it's quite simple though, just some code for making a div appear and how it should look. So here it is:

```js
window.onload = function() {
  setTimeout(appeardiv, 30000);
}

function appeardiv() {
  document.getElementById("acceptbox3").style.display = "block"
}
```

```css
.accept_square3 {
  background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
  position: fixed;
  top: 55.9%;
  left: 43.2%;
  height: 5vw;
  width: 13vw;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="acceptbox3" class="accept_square3"></div>
```

Okay, I think this was all of the script.

Comment: Use this event `onclick` this event invoke when element is clicked, query the element you want to hide and set `display` as none ([Example](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_style_display))

Comment: The reason behind you are not able to find because your question is little vauge, search for something like this: how to register a click event listener in javascript,How to hide an element by javascript. Its always hard at first time because of unfamiliarity of the right keywords, best of luck. Other folks: Downvoting without reason leads new user frusted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like what you need is just to add a `click` handler like so

```
function appeardiv() {
  const acceptBox = document.getElementById("acceptbox3");
  acceptBox.style.display = "block";
  acceptBox.onclick = () => acceptBox.remove();
}
```

If you are not familiar with arrow functions, you may also use ordinary functions:

```
  acceptBox.onclick = function() { acceptBox.remove() };
```

Also, if you need to add more than one handler, you may use

```
  acceptBox.addEventListener(() => acceptBox.remove());
```

instead.

The result is (let me decrease the timeout, though):

```js
window.onload = function() {
  setTimeout(appeardiv, 1000);
}

function appeardiv() {
  const acceptBox = document.getElementById("acceptbox3");
  acceptBox.style.display = "block";
  acceptBox.onclick = () => acceptBox.remove();
}
```

```css
.accept_square3 {
  background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
  position: fixed;
  top: 55.9%;
  left: 43.2%;
  height: 5vw;
  width: 13vw;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="acceptbox3" class="accept_square3"></div>
```

Comment: Okay sorry for the late reply but I got it working so when clicked it gets removed but may I ask since I still have a bit of trouble understanding JS. How do I make it so more than one div gets removed by the click?

Sorry if you already answered this in the comment but I'm quite bad at JS language.

Comment: @Ratic well, basically you set a click handler which is a function: `acceptBox.onclick = function() { acceptBox.remove() };`, inside this function you can do whatever you want, for instance remove couple of elements: `acceptBox.onclick = function() { acceptBox.remove(); anotherElement.remove(); };`. If you are not familiar with the arrow functions notation, read about it too, but it's not that important for the current task

Comment: Alright, this finally somewhat worked, thank you so much, took forever to finally get this done.

Answer (score -1):

Not sure if I understand what you mean here. If you want to hide a div if cliccked, this should do the trick:

```
("#yourDiv").on("click", function() { ("#yourDiv").hide() });
```